# "ndk-build finish with non-zero exit value 2" while compiling textfairy project

Tags: android, c++, maven, android-ndk, ndk-build

I have been in this issue for one week. I'm not able to sort out, please help me!
I follow all the steps in the guide (https://github.com/renard314/textfairy#building-with-gradle) like 10 times and I still have the same error.
In the web I found a lot of people had this problem and I try all their solution but still don't work.
I have a MacBook Pro

`Information:Gradle tasks [:app:generateDevelopDebugSources, :app:generateDevelopDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:prepareDevelopDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:compileDevelopDebugSources, :app:compileDevelopDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:compileDevelopDebugUnitTestSources, :tess-two:tess-two:generateDebugSources, :tess-two:tess-two:mockableAndroidJar, :tess-two:tess-two:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :tess-two:tess-two:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :tess-two:tess-two:compileDebugSources, :tess-two:tess-two:compileDebugUnitTestSources, :tess-two:tess-two:compileDebugAndroidTestSources]`

`Error:Execution failed for task ':tess-two:tess-two:ndkBuild'.`

Process 'command '/Users/giuliopettenuzzo/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/ndk-build'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

when I try to execute this commnd this is what I see this info:

`Initialized native services in: /Users/giuliopettenuzzo/.gradle/native
Found daemon DaemonInfo{pid=22739, address=[9ff26fe0-163c-468c-95ea-a30bf761b19b port:52841, addresses:[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, /127.0.0.1]], state=Idle, lastBusy=1501756593936, context=DefaultDaemonContext[uid=c569827f-7ca0-4b6e-8d43-9306b578605e,javaHome=/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home,daemonRegistryDir=/Users/giuliopettenuzzo/.gradle/daemon,pid=22739,idleTimeout=10800000,daemonOpts=-XX:MaxPermSize=512m,-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8,-Duser.country=IT,-Duser.language=it,-Duser.variant]}`
however its context does not match the desired criteria.
Java home is different.

Wanted: `DefaultDaemonContext[uid=null,javaHome=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home,daemonRegistryDir=/Users/giuliopettenuzzo/.gradle/daemon,pid=23067,idleTimeout=null,daemonOpts=-XX:MaxPermSize=512m,-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8,-Duser.country=IT,-Duser.language=it,-Duser.variant]
Actual: DefaultDaemonContext[uid=c569827f-7ca0-4b6e-8d43-9306b578605e,javaHome=/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home,daemonRegistryDir=/Users/giuliopettenuzzo/.gradle/daemon,pid=22739,idleTimeout=10800000,daemonOpts=-XX:MaxPermSize=512m,-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8,-Duser.country=IT,-Duser.language=it,-Duser.variant]`

Looking for a different daemon...

`[armeabi-v7a] Compile        : lept <= adaptmap.c
make: /Users/giuliopettenuzzo/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: Command not found
make: *** [/Users/giuliopettenuzzo/AndroidStudioProjects/textfairy/tess-two/tess-two/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/lept/src/src/adaptmap.o] Error 127
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
[armeabi-v7a] Compile        : lept <= affine.c
make: /Users/giuliopettenuzzo/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: Command not found
make: *** [/Users/giuliopettenuzzo/AndroidStudioProjects/textfairy/tess-two/tess-two/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/lept/src/src/affine.o] Error 127
[armeabi-v7a] Compile        : lept <= affinecompose.c
make: /Users/giuliopettenuzzo/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: Command not found
make: *** [/Users/giuliopettenuzzo/AndroidStudioProjects/textfairy/tess-two/tess-two/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/lept/src/src/affinecompose.o] Error 127
:tess-two:tess-two:ndkBuild FAILED
:tess-two:tess-two:ndkBuild (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 6,5,main]) completed. Took 0.642 secs.`

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':tess-two:tess-two:ndkBuild'.

  > Process 'command '/Users/giuliopettenuzzo/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/ndk-build'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

`Total time: 2.528 secs
Stopped 0 worker daemon(s).
Received result Failure[value=org.gradle.initialization.ReportedException: org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: Execution failed for task ':tess-two:tess-two:ndkBuild'.] from daemon DaemonInfo{pid=19466, address=[ae62748c-dbc0-48ed-a2da-1eed52e8dfd6 port:52129, addresses:[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, /127.0.0.1]], state=Idle, lastBusy=1501757699726, context=DefaultDaemonContext[uid=0f9deada-80eb-4945-9840-eeb96ed44e55,javaHome=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home,daemonRegistryDir=/Users/giuliopettenuzzo/.gradle/daemon,pid=19466,idleTimeout=10800000,daemonOpts=-XX:MaxPermSize=512m,-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8,-Duser.country=IT,-Duser.language=it,-Duser.variant]} (build should be done).`

Comment: See https://github.com/renard314/textfairy/issues/138#issuecomment-287583567. Same fix should work for you too.

Comment: yeh man you save my life

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> make: /Users/giuliopettenuzzo/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: Command not found

Looks like your NDK install is incomplete.